# iOS app approval: Does Apple check the binary for specific strings?

Tags: ios

This may be stupid question.  I have app with a bunch of URLs stored as strings in a Constants.h file.  A couple of them point to a site where content could be purchased outside the App.  Apple rejected the binary submission to the App Store for this.  All of the links to the external site were removed from the App but the URLs are still stored in the Constants.h file, they're just not used anywhere anymore.  The App got rejected again for the same reason (even though the App does not link to an external site).

I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible or probably that Apple is parsing my binary and flagging unused string URLs?

Comment: what reason for the second rejection?

Comment: You know that headers aren't compiled right?  They're still perfectly available within the app package.  It's all a few terminal commands away.

Comment: @Veelian - reason for rejection was 11.13 as stated by darvidsOn in approved answer.

Comment: @CodaFi - I didn't realize that but that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks so much.  I'm learning a lot right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very possible, yes.

App Store Review Guideline 11.13 states:

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Understandably, "link to external mechanisms" is ambiguous here and could mean "contain any URL where one can purchase app content", but I can't say for sure that's what that means.

To make sure you steer clear of the guideline though, I would recommend in your Constants.h file adding a preprocessor directive so that the purchasing URLs aren't even present in the app bundle:

```
#ifdef PURCHASE_URLS
static NSString* externalPurchaseURL = @"http://mywebsite.com/purchase_content";
#endif
```

(note that you should not have `Constants.h` in your Copy Headers build step)

Then you can add the URLs in for debug builds by adding `PURCHASE_URLS` to "Preprocessor Macros" (in fact, probably "Preprocessor Macros Not Used In Precompiled Headers", since you're not doing it in your `_Prefix.pch` file) in your project's Build Settings, but omit them in the version you submit to the App Store by not defining them for the Distribution build.

Comment: ah, got it.  thanks so much!  I'll make the update and resubmit.